# How do I get the node in an XML document when given a row and column or an index in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have a text area that is populated with the contents of an XML document. I'm trying to get the node that the user has placed his cursor in.

I can easily get the row and column or the index of the cursor. I can also create an XML object via `new XML(textarea.text)`.

What would be great is if there is a `XML.getNodeAtPosition(index)` or `XML.getNodeAtPosition(row, column)` method.

Here is example code:

```
var row:int = 100;
var column:int = 10;
var xmlText:String = fileLoader.data as String;
textarea.text = xmlText;
textarea.setAnchor(row, column); // simulate user cursor
var xml:XML = new XML(textarea.text);
var node:XML = xml.getNodeAt(row, column);
```

**Note:**
The XML may be edited by the user and may not be valid XML. I don't think Flash will create an XML object unless it is completely valid but it would be great if it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oook, I made this thing working. First, let me explain the results. You must feed a valid XML string to this class:

```
var S:String = '<?xml version="123" ?><node b=\'"2\'><? oook ?><innernode a = "\'1" /><!-- 123 --><![CDATA[ 456 ]]>text</node>';
var A:ParXMLer =  new ParXMLer(S);
```

It traverses source string and resulting XML simultaneously and produces a list of slices with begin/end text indices, a part of source text that represent the slice and a reference to appropriate XML node (yes, the leading **<?xml ... ?>** clause is ignored as it does not go to XML object):

```
[NODE 22:107] <node b='"2'><? oook ?><innernode a = "'1" /><!-- 123 --><![CDATA[ 456 ]]>text</node>
[HEAD 22:35] <node b='"2'>
[PI 35:45] <? oook ?>
[NODE 45:67] <innernode a = "'1" />
[COMMENT 67:79] <!-- 123 -->
[CDATA 79:96] <![CDATA[ 456 ]]>
[TEXT 96:100] text
[TAIL 100:107] </node>
```

Then, the class. Use the method **.nodeByIndex(index:int):XML** to obtain the reference to the most relevant XML node.

```
package
{
    public class ParXMLer
    {
        public var targetXML:XML;
        public var parseIndex:int;
        public var sourceText:String;

        public var slices:Vector.<XMLSlice> = new Vector.<XMLSlice>();

        public function ParXMLer(source:String, target:XML = null)
        {
            XML.ignoreComments = false;
            XML.ignoreProcessingInstructions = false;

            try
            {
                if (target == null) target = new XML(source);
            }
            catch (fail:Error)
            {
                trace(fail);
            }

            parseIndex = 0;
            targetXML = target;
            sourceText = source;

            parseNode(targetXML);
        }

        // Obtain the most relevant XML node by its source string index.
        public function nodeByIndex(index:int):XML
        {
            var result:XMLSlice;

            for each (var aSlice:XMLSlice in slices)
            {
                if (aSlice.begin > index) continue;
                if (aSlice.end <= index) continue;

                if (result == null)
                {
                    result = aSlice;
                }
                else if (aSlice.begin > result.begin)
                {
                    result = aSlice;
                }
            }

            if (result == null) return null;

            return result.node;
        }

        public function toString():String
        {
            return slices.join("\n");
        }

        // Figure the given node type and parse it accordingly.
        private function parseNode(X:XML):void
        {
            var aKind:String = X.nodeKind();

            switch (aKind)
            {
                case "element":
                    parseElement(X);
                    break;

                case "text":
                    parseText(X);
                    break;

                case "comment":
                    parseComment(X);
                    break;

                case "processing-instruction":
                    parsePi(X);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Parse normal XML node.
        private function parseElement(X:XML):void
        {
            var aHead:XMLSlice = parseHead(X);

            if (aHead.type == XMLSlice.WHOLE)
            {
                slices.push(aHead);
                return;
            }

            var result:XMLSlice = new XMLSlice();

            result.node = X;
            result.begin = aHead.begin;
            result.type = XMLSlice.WHOLE;

            slices.push(result, aHead);

            parseKids(X);

            var aTail:XMLSlice = parseTail(X);

            slices.push(aTail);

            result.end = aTail.end;
            result.text = sourceText.substring(result.begin, result.end);
        }

        // Parse </close> tailing tag.
        private function parseTail(X:XML):XMLSlice
        {
            var result:XMLSlice = new XMLSlice();

            result.node = X;
            result.type = XMLSlice.TAIL;
            result.begin = sourceText.indexOf("</", parseIndex);

            parseIndex = result.begin + 2;

            result.end = sourceText.indexOf(">", parseIndex) + 1;

            parseIndex = result.end;

            result.text = sourceText.substring(result.begin, result.end);

            return result;
        }

        // Parse XML node children.
        private function parseKids(X:XML):void
        {
            var aList:XMLList = X.children();

            for (var i:int = 0; i < aList.length(); i++)
            {
                var aChild:XML = aList[i];
                parseNode(aChild);
            }
        }

        // Parse XML node <open ... > tag.
        private function parseHead(X:XML):XMLSlice
        {
            var result:XMLSlice = new XMLSlice();
            var aTag:String = "<" + X.name();

            result.node = X;
            result.begin = sourceText.indexOf(aTag, parseIndex);

            parseIndex = result.begin + aTag.length;

            var aClause:XMLClause = avoidQuotes("/>", ">");

            result.end = aClause.index + aClause.text.length;
            result.text = sourceText.substring(result.begin, result.end);

            switch (aClause.text)
            {
                case "/>":
                    result.type = XMLSlice.WHOLE;
                    break;

                case ">":
                    result.type = XMLSlice.HEAD;
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }

        // Search for the foremost occurrence of ANY of the given arguments.
        private function search(...rest:Array):XMLClause
        {
            var result:XMLClause = new XMLClause();

            for each (var anItem:String in rest)
            {
                var anIndex:int = sourceText.indexOf(anItem, parseIndex);

                if (anIndex < 0) continue;
                if (anIndex < result.index)
                {
                    result.index = anIndex;
                    result.text = anItem;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        // Search for matching quote with regard to "\"" and '\'' cases.
        private function unquote(quote:String):void
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var aClause:XMLClause = search("\\" + quote, quote);

                parseIndex = aClause.index + aClause.text.length;
                if (aClause.text == quote) return;
            }
        }

        // Find the end of the tag avoiding text in the quotes.
        private function avoidQuotes(...rest:Array):XMLClause
        {
            var aList:Array = ['"', "'"].concat(rest);

            while (true)
            {
                var result:XMLClause = search.apply(this, aList);

                switch (result.text)
                {
                    case '"':
                    case "'":
                        unquote(result.text);
                        break;

                    default:
                        return result;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        // Parse <? ... ?> tag.
        private function parsePi(X:XML):void
        {
            var result:XMLSlice = new XMLSlice();

            result.node = X;
            result.type = XMLSlice.PI;
            result.begin = sourceText.indexOf("<?", parseIndex);

            parseIndex = result.begin + 2;

            var aClause:XMLClause = avoidQuotes("?>");

            result.end = aClause.index + 2;
            result.text = sourceText.substring(result.begin, result.end);

            slices.push(result);
        }

        // Parse <!-- ... --> tag.
        private function parseComment(X:XML):void
        {
            var result:XMLSlice = new XMLSlice();

            result.node = X;
            result.type = XMLSlice.COMMENT;
            result.begin = sourceText.indexOf("<!--", parseIndex);
            result.end = sourceText.indexOf("-->", result.begin) + 3;
            result.text = sourceText.substring(result.begin, result.end);

            parseIndex = result.end;
            slices.push(result);
        }

        static private const SPACES:String = " \n\r\t";

        private function eatWhitespaces():void
        {
            while (SPACES.indexOf(sourceText.charAt(parseIndex)) > -1) parseIndex++;
        }

        // Parse plain text tag or <![CDATA[ ... ]]> tag.
        private function parseText(X:XML):void
        {
            eatWhitespaces();

            var result:XMLSlice = new XMLSlice();

            if (sourceText.indexOf("<![CDATA[", parseIndex) == parseIndex)
            {
                result.type = XMLSlice.CDATA;
                result.begin = sourceText.indexOf("<![CDATA[", parseIndex);
                result.end = sourceText.indexOf("]]>", result.begin) + 3;
            }
            else
            {
                result.type = XMLSlice.TEXT;
                result.begin = parseIndex;
                result.end = sourceText.indexOf("<", parseIndex);
            }

            result.node = X;
            result.text = sourceText.substring(result.begin, result.end);

            parseIndex = result.end;
            slices.push(result);
        }
    }
}

internal class XMLSlice
{
    static public const COMMENT:String = "COMMENT";
    static public const CDATA:String = "CDATA";
    static public const TEXT:String = "TEXT";
    static public const PI:String = "PI";
    static public const WHOLE:String = "NODE";
    static public const HEAD:String = "HEAD";
    static public const TAIL:String = "TAIL";

    public var type:String;
    public var begin:int;
    public var end:int;
    public var node:XML;
    public var text:String;

    public function get length():int { return text.length; }
    public function toString():String { return "[" + type + " " + begin + ":" + end + "] " + text; }
}

internal class XMLClause
{
    public var index:int = int.MAX_VALUE;
    public var text:String = null;
}
```

Comment: This looks amazing!

Comment: I do not understand this though, `[NODE 22:107]`. Should it be NODE 0:107?

Comment: As I **mentioned** in the description: the leading **<?xml ... ?>** clause is ignored as it does not go to XML object.

Answer (score 0):

Xml is a tree structure like xmlDoc[0][1][5][3]. Once you think about it like that your question doesn't quite make sense.

The approach I would take to get the selected node under the cursor is to recursively search backward the text in the text area to find the node chain names `<YourNodeName <YourParentNodeName <YourGrandParentNodeName` until you get to the root. Then you can dot down through the xml with e4x like `xmlDoc.YourGrandParentNodeName.YourParentNodeName.YourNodeName` to get the node.

Comment: That solution does not take into account: identical sibling nodes (which are totally normal on XML), comment nodes (they have no name and ignored by default), <![CDATA[ ]]> nodes.